# ec2 workflow microsoft / apple

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm switching over to EC2 and obviously it's easiest to manage instances through a command line rather than some crappy web interface, but I work on a PC and have everything set up in Windows. What is the best way to work with dev server instances? Putty? Is there an alternative? What do you guys use?

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "manage instances".

If you mean the ability to launch new instances from an AMI, configure security groups, manage EIP's and so on, the ElasticFox plugin to Firefox is great (in spite of having occasionally buggy releases).  The command line tools supplied by Amazon for this purpose could be a good basis if you're writing automated scripts, but I find ElasticFox much better for my work.

To work directly on the instances, I use WinSCP for both Windows and Linux instances (I installed a third-party SFTP server for Windows), PuTTY for Linux and Remote Desktop for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I manage both Linux and Windows EC2 instances for a couple of different businesses.

For the Windows boxes I normally connect via Remote Desktop to do virtually everything. For Linux I use WinSCP and PuTTY consoles.

For EC2-specific operations I use the Amazon web console or the Amazon-supplied scripts from my PC.

Comment: ok thank you! winscp and putty are what I'm using now, but when I developk, it becomes a hastle sometimes